# urldownloadtofile only prefetch

Tags: c, windows, urlmon

I am making a program that downloads files to a windows. To do so i used urlmon and the urldownload to file function. Whenever i download a file with the function in question in my windows i only get a prefetch file, but i can't find the file on my hard drive. Please tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *UDTF)(LPVOID, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, DWORD, LPVOID);

int dl_url(char *url, char *path)
{
    int q = 1;
    HMODULE hDll;
    UDTF URLDownloadToFile;

    if((hDll = LoadLibrary("urlmon")))
    {
        if((URLDownloadToFile = (UDTF)GetProcAddress(hDll, "URLDownloadToFileA")))
        {
            if(URLDownloadToFile(0, url, path, 0, 0) == 0)
            q = 0;
        }
        FreeLibrary(hDll);
    }

    return q;
}
```

Note: I use a 32 bit windows xp to test this program.

Comment: There are folders in your project directory called "Release" and "Debug", that's where your *.exe is file is at. Look in those directories. Or give full path name for "path". Also your style of programming is wrong. Turn on compiler warning to level 4.

Comment: I do not have any Release nor Debug directory in my file project. To compile this i use minwg on ubuntu and i transfer the file over on my windows xp using a local webserver. And i did give a full name to path but still no result. And the link is correct to.